# Select Array Element by Property Value Postgres Jsonb

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb

I have an object stored in a jsonb column in my Postgres database.

The data in the column looks like this:

```
{
    "results": [
        {
            "createdByApp": "yes",
            "externalApps": [
                {
                    "modifiedByUser": "User-1",
                    "modifiedDate": "2023-09-12T08:43:10.779",
                    "name": "test1"
                },
                {
                    "modifiedByUser": "User-2",
                    "modifiedDate": "2023-09-12T08:43:10.779",
                    "name": "test2"
                },
                {
                    "modifiedByUser": "User-3",
                    "modifiedDate": "2023-09-12T08:43:10.779",
                    "name": "test3"
                }
            ],
            "modifiedByApp": "7572b20b-a594-48dd-8ab3-8bc2718a23bd"
        }
    ]
}
```

What I am trying to do is select the `name` of the `externalApp` that was modified by `User-2`.

I am able to pull the external apps as a json object by using:

`select (act."MessageBody"::json->'results'->0)->>'externalApps' as extApps`

This gives me the array of objects inside `externalApps`.

But from there I cannot find a way to select the `name` for modifiedByUser = `User-2`

I cannot guarantee the User-2 modified app is always the second element in the array. How can I search through the array and select a value if the `modifiedByUser` value matches?

Comment: What's your PostgreSQL version?

Comment: I am using 11.18, and I was able to fix the problem by using `cross join lateral jsonb_array_elements((act."MessageBody"::jsonb->'results'->0)->'externalApps') externalApps` then including  `where externalApps->>'modifiedByUser' = 'User-2'`

Comment: Just in case: yesterday's 11.22 is the last minor release of v11 and as of today, it reached [end of life and is no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/). Consider an update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PostgreSQL 12 and above, you can use a [`jsonb_path_query()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#id-1.5.8.22.8.13.2.2.19.1.1.1) function:  [db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/xlTp6fXX)

```sql
select jsonb_path_query( act."MessageBody"::jsonb
                        ,'$.results[*]
                           .externalApps[*]
                           ?(@.modifiedByUser==$var)
                           .name'
                        ,jsonb_build_object('var','User-2'))
from act;
```

| jsonb_path_query |
| --- |
| "test2" |

[JSONPath](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html#DATATYPE-JSONPATH) syntax offers both array wildcards `[*]` and a filter expression `?()`. You can also pass the `user` you're looking for dynamically, as a variable from the outside.

---

Support for [`jsonb_array_elements()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#id-1.5.8.22.8.13.2.2.1.1.2.1) reaches all the way back to 9.4, so you can also:

```
select e['name'] as extApps
from act, jsonb_array_elements(act."MessageBody"::jsonb
                                ->'results'
                                ->0
                                ->'externalApps')_(e)
where e->>'modifiedByUser'='User-2';
```

| extapps |
| --- |
| "test2" |

If you're not sure your `externalApps` will be the 0th element of `results`, you're going to need two of those:

```sql
select e2['name'] as extApps
from act, 
     jsonb_array_elements(act."MessageBody"::jsonb->'results')j1(e),
     jsonb_array_elements(e->'externalApps')j2(e2)
where e2->>'modifiedByUser'='User-2';
```

| extapps |
| --- |
| "test2" |

Note these are all set-returning functions, so there are lots of [lateral joins](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-LATERAL) behind the scenes.